# ProcessBuilder doesn't create file on server

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm using process builder to run `psql` command from postgres to call `copy` commands to export some tables.

My workflow are the following:

```
String sql = "\"\\copy ( SELECT * from table ) TO '/folder' DELIMITER '|' NULL '\\N'\";

List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
commands.add("sudo");
commands.add("-u");
commands.add("root");
commands.add("psql");
commands.add("-h");
commands.add("host");
commands.add("-U");
commands.add("postgres");
commands.add("-d");
commands.add("database");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add(sql);

ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(commands);

Process execution = process.start();
execution.waitFor(); // each calling to export data wait a little to generate next;
```

The following commands will turns on final in that commands:

```
sudo -u root psql -h host -U postgres -d database_user -c \copy ( select * from table TO "/folder/file.txt/" DELIMITER '|' NULL '\\N'" )
```

But the `file.txt` isn't created in server, even run as `root`.

Local works fine. But when is ran within server the commands don't runs.
Where are the problem?

Comment: Are you using Windows as your local developer machine and Linux as a server?

Comment: That's right.
I've already tried using process.waitFor() and just process.start() with Thread.sleep(), cause I've notice that the files was stored in disc after a time, but none of these options worked. Local ( windows ) works everything fine, the problem is on server ( linux )

Comment: Linux paths use "/".Try changing that and see if it works on the server.

Comment: @BugHunter I've update the content with correct slash, I've putted the windows's slash. I use File.separator Java's constant, then on windows it will show "\" and on server "/" . The command runs fine on serve by copy paste on command line but via ProcessBuilder don't, I don't understant why...

Comment: @Marlysson What is the content of the output stream and error stream of the `Process` object? Please [edit] your question to include the content of these streams.

Comment: @Progman to do this ( see erros ) means the exception that are generated or defining the redirectError() ? I'm using the exception to handle the errors, but no one appears.

Comment: My funcionality it's: export database data to disk then compact them in one zip. On compact files step raises the exception: "no are files to compact" cause the files wasn't create in disk. I don't put the next step ( compression because it doesn't work because the export don't too )

Comment: @Marlysson The process you are calling might generate an output which you currently don't check. Use the methods like `Process.getErrorStream()`/`Process.getInputStream()` or `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput()`/`ProcessBuilder.redirectError()` to get or redirect the output/error stream and check its content.

Comment: It's ok, I will verify this. Many attempts trying works on server and local works fine...

Do you already put some script using ProcessBuilder in production?

Whatever to use the ErrorStream or InputStream?

Comment: @Marlysson Check both streams because both of them can contain useful information.

Comment: Folks, I've solved my problem with ProcessBuilder. I was scaping the command after -c argument.. Instead -c "command" I used -c command ( without quotation marks). So worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

Just remove the quotation marks of "-c" argument, that is, without scaping the final string.

Instead:

```
sudo -u root psql -h host -U postgres -d database_user -c \copy "( select * from table TO '/folder/file.txt/') DELIMITER '|' NULL '\\N'
```

I used:

```
sudo -u root psql -h host -U postgres -d database_user -c \copy ( select * from table TO '/folder/file.txt/') DELIMITER '|' NULL '\\N'
```